# ADC for low signal (microvolts)

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, voltage, adc, voltage-measurement

I am a newbie to electronics

I have a sensor that can provide a range of [400 microvolts - 5 Volts] 
I want to transform this signal into Digital so that i can read it on computer, I'm seeking a quality information without noise or anythinging that can reduce it quality
I searched into Arduino but it range is between [0.0048V - 5V] 
what can I use as materials? procedures? ressources to learn?
any information can Help at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic parameter of an ADC is it's resolution and sampling speed.

Sampling speed is pretty obvious - it tells you how often a sample (digital value) is produced. It's expressed in Hz. This determines if you can detect fast changes in the signal.

The other thing is resolution. It's expressed in bits. If you have a 8-bit converter that means that it produces digital values between 0-255 (or 2^8=256 values). If your ADC has a 5V reference voltage (or to simplify in the case of an Arduino, a 5V power supply) that means that the entire range is divided into 256 equal parts. So 5V/(2^8)=0.02V is the smallest value your ADC can detect (i.e. 0x00 => 0V, 0x01 => 0.02V, 0x02 => 0.04V and so on).

The arduino has a 10-bit ADC so that gives 5V/(2^10)=0.00488V. If you want more resolution you can look for how much bits you need. In your case: 5/(2^14)= 0.000305V would be enough. However I think that it might be easier to find and audio range ADC chip with an SPI bus output to communicate with the arduino (usually audio ADCs use the I2S bus for output). Those would go to 16-bits, so you'll be well covered.

Alternatively, if your signal is slow and you don't need fast sampling speeds, you can go for data acquisition chips like ADS1100 of ADS1113. The sampling rate is in the order of a few hundred Hz.

Comment: I'm dealing with a Seismic signal, more precisely short period seismometer that can detect small fast and first to arrive waves, resolution and speed are important for me 
I liked the idea of having a 0.000305V as Min; but does that mean,in case of using arduino + audio ADC chip, i will be able to have the higher end too ? i mean 5V?

Comment: The ADS1113 has a 16-bit resolution and works with a differential input. If used as a single ended device you get 15-bits. It can operate with a 5V supply, so you'll get 5V/(2^15)=153µV. The maximum sampling date is 840Hz. This allows you to detect signals of at most 420Hz (Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem). Not sure if that's enough for seismic activity.